# Using VBA to extract data from website, but getting run time error '91'

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

Quite new to VBA, having a problem with this error code.

> run time error '91' object variable or With block variable not set

I'm trying to extract data from a website and past to a excel document. My Excel doc is `Book2` and my module is called `Module1`. I'll paste the code below.

```
Sub WebNavigate()    
    Dim CreatingObject As Object
    Dim WebNavigate As Object

    Set objIE = CreatingObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    WebSite = "website link"
    With objIE
        .Visable = True
        .navigate WebSite
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set elements = .document.getElementByClass("timark")
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 8) = element.innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your spelling of visible is incorrect - and you are including an 'i' that does not appear to be defined in the Sheet1.Cells line.

Comment: I recommend to use `Option Explicit` to avoid typos (`.Visable` vs `.Visible`)

Comment: Where are you New-ing CreatingObject?  Or do you really want to be using `CreateObject`?

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of HTML/URL to go with:

1) You are spelling of `Visible` is incorrect

2) The following:

```
Set elements = .document.getElementByClass("timark")
```

Is missing an `s` as it returns a collection and should be `ClassName`:

```
Set elements = .document.getElementsByClassName("timark")
```

3) You may need a pause or loop to ensure `elements` is available on the page.

4) This

```
Sheet1.Cells(i, 8) = element.innerText
```

You don't yet have `element` declared and assigned (you also don't have `elements` declared) . You may use in a `For Loop`.

e.g.

```
 Dim element As Object, elements As Object
 Set elements = .document.getElementsByClassName("timark")
 For each element in elements
```

5) `Creating` should be `Create` (also as noted) and you need to declare `objIE`

```
Dim objIE As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

6) `i` is not declared anywhere and must be greater than 1 when it is as there is no cell with row 0 in the sheet. Also, `i` would indicate a Loop of which there is no sign and when in a loop should be incremented to avoid overwriting the same cell.

7)  `Dim WebNavigate As Object` is unassigned and not needed at present in the code.

8) To avoid many of the above use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code (As already mentioned).

Comment: Did this make a difference?